# Autotune Embedding with Fasttext

Tags: nlp, embedding, hyperparameters, fasttext

I have trained word embeddings using Fasttext - train.unsuperwised.
Is there a way to autotune the hyperparameters for this? Documentation gives autotuning for supervised training but I am not sure how supervised training can be done for embeddings.

Answer (score 1):

You can used the `supervised` mode for embeddings, if you have target labels to predict per input text. But then the embeddings will be optimized for that classification purpose, rather than the more general usefulness people usually expect from unsupervised training.

Because such metaparameter optimization ("autotune") only makes sense if testing the results against a goal with clear right/wrong answers, it likely only works for the supervised mode, as shown by the docs.

If you're using the (normal, unsupervised) word-vectors for some other downstream task of your own, and you can create a repeatable evaluation for that task, you should write your own code to perform a search for the best metaparameters.